# Streets and Trips data import wizard - use address instead of long/lat

Tags: geolocation

Is there a way to ether force Streets and Trips to always pin by address even if long/lat data is present, or to have streets and trips pin by address for rows that are missing long/lat data?

We download our routing data from a third party where there is no guarantee that all rows will have long/lat data but will always have an address.  However when using the import wizard in Streets and Trips (versions 2011 through 2013), if streets detects long and lat columns it will default to pinning by long/lat data and skip any rows that do not have long/lat data.

So far the only workarounds I have found for this issue are overly complicated for employees who are not computer savvy.  I'm hoping there is a setting that can force streets to only use the address, or use the address in cases where long/lat data is missing.

The data files are comma separated files that are downloaded from a third party webpage.  No other formats are available.

Comment: what workarounds are you referring to? maybe they can be scripted/macro'ed somehow?

Comment: @Znau Only two methods I've found so far are to open the data file (csv) in open office and delete the long/lat columns or change the long/lat columns in the data import wizard to not selected.  Both seem like easy things to do but can be surprisingly overwhelming for some of our employees.

Comment: @nixda i am not the QA, i think you meant gSamp.

Comment: @gSamp Can you provide an anonymized example of an input and the according output file (@Znau: sry :p)

Comment: @nixda I have added an example csv file.

Comment: Can't you provide your employees with sanitised data? Or perhaps use a script that will be easy for them to run and will delete the unwanted data/columns?

Comment: @Karan unfortunately, the data is downloaded from a third party website directly to each employee's computer, so I have no way to modify the data before it hits their station.  I am considering writing an app they can run the data though per Znau and your comments, but I was still hoping there could be a setting I could change in Streets that would allow everything to work as intended without introducing any new steps in the process the employees must follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer, according to my research, is there is no way to modify the default behavior of Streets and Trips, at least for this one feature.  The only way to change the way streets will route is to modify the data before importing or changing the column types in the import data dialog.  If Streets knows long/lat data is present, it will route only by long/lat data, skipping any rows that do not have long/lat data.  As an added bonus, Streets will not produce any warning or indication that rows were skipped or that the map is incomplete.  I have confirmed this with versions 2009, 2011, and 2013.